# nginx angularjs in root, codeigniter in subdir

Tags: php, nginx

I have a main website in the root folder with AngularJS, this one also rewrite URL's to index.html and this is working.

Then in subdirectory manage I have a code igniter installation. 
However when I go in there I get redirected to the angular website.

The codeigniter used to work on apache server, I don't use rewrite for codeigniter.

My config is:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com;

    location /manage {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri /index.html?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Do I need extra configuration for the manage folder?
I have set my base_url in codeigniter to http://example.com/manage/

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: My question was not about programming but about the configuration of the nginx webserver. Anyway I managed to fix it. By modifying the line in location /manage to try_files $uri $uri/ /manage/index.php?$args;